# Excel formula to pick a cell value if condition not verified

Tags: microsoft-excel

I’m trying to create a VBA formula and not macro that picks the “ID’s” instead of “-” (dashes).
The image below is an example of what I’m trying to do, for each row I want to pick the ID (number or text, written in cells where there aren't dashes).

[image: a]

In other words, I need a formula that picks ID from a selected row (i.e. [F17:P17]).
The formula will delivery the value of the cell that doesn't contain “-”.

Example:

```
IF(logical_test;”pick a ID (number or text)”;”-”)
```

Unfortunately there’s not a formula that does the opposite job as `IF`, kind of `IFNOT`. `IFNA` doesn't help either.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that any non-dash from columns F to P will be a repetition? Or are you using G through P as the source and F as the answer?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but there is a of doing IFNOT. Try: IF(NOT(test),true,false)

Answer (score 3):

In I17, put `=CONCATENATE(C17,D17,E17,F17,G17,H17)`. This will give you something like `----1282525-`.

Then in J17, put `=SUBSTITUTE(I17,"-","")`. This will remove the dashes, leaving you the single non-dash answer.

You may then fill down the formulas in these columns.

Comment: Thanks rajah9, worked beautifully. I combined both formulas you gave me to be like:

`=SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(G17;H17;I17;J17;K17;L17;M17;N17;O17;P17);"-";"")`

Answer (score 0):

This formula will give you the last value in the row that isn't a dash

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(G17:P17<>"-"),G17:P17)`